# How to validate minimun date for 2 digits years with Yup and Moment

Tags: date, validation, momentjs, yup

I'm using Formik defining my validations with Yup schema. I want to validate a credit card validation date, the allowed formats are: 'MM/YYYY' or 'MM/YY'. Those formats are not allowed with the normal yup.date schema (to my knowledge).

There is way to redefine an schema type, this is what I did to allow those formats using Moment js. I added a new **format** method like this:

```
const yup = require('yup');
const moment = require('moment');

const invalidDate = new Date('');

yup.addMethod(yup.date, 'format', (formats, parseStrict) => (
  this.transform((value, originalValue) => {
    if (this.isType(value)) return value;
    const newValue = moment(originalValue, formats, parseStrict);
    return newValue.isValid() ? newValue.toDate() : invalidDate;
  })
));
```

And this is how I used:

```
const dateMin = moment().endOf('month').format('MM/YYYY');
Yup.object().shape({
   dateExp: Yup.date()
    .format(['MM/YYYY', 'MM/YY'], true)
    .typeError(t('validationExpDate'))
    .required(t('validationRequired'))
    .min(dateMin, t('validationMinDate', { date: dateMin })),
});
```

The problem with this approach is that I'm not able to validate the min date for 2 digit years, only works for 4 digits.

When I try to change my **dateMin** const like this:

```
const dateMin = moment().endOf('month').format(['MM/YYYY', 'MM/YY']);
```

When I do this, it stop validating everything, is like is not supported.

Does someone has any ideas of how to do this? Maybe my approach is not the best, what would be the correct way to accomplish it?

Thanks in advance!